# Itk Package error in Polsarpro v.5.4

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, itk

I am trying to run Polsarpro v.5.4, but i got this error when i enetered the prog.

```
can't find package Itk
can't find package Itk
    while executing
"package require Itk"
    (file "GUI/bmp_process/ViewBMPFile.tcl" line 28)
    invoked from within
"source "GUI/bmp_process/ViewBMPFile.tcl""
    invoked from within
".top1.fra66.cpd69.but93 invoke"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list $w invoke]"
    (procedure "tk::ButtonUp" line 22)
    invoked from within
"tk::ButtonUp .top1.fra66.cpd69.but93"
    (command bound to event)
```

I installed Itk package in my system (fedora 23) and i contact ESA, they told me i have to install tcl-tk and Active-Tcl package and i already installed them, but it gave me the same error.
Please help.

Many thanks

Comment: The error message suggests _very_ strongly that you haven't installed Itk. If you have, then the message must be interpretted to say that Tcl _can't find_ the package. I don't use Itk myself, but the package almost certainly includes a file calle pkgIndex.tcl. Does the directory containing that file appear in the list of directories which Tcl searches? That's held by the auto_path variable? If not, try adding it.

Comment: I added it, but still it does not work

Comment: So, you've added the directory containing Itk's pkgIndex.tcl file to auto_path and get the same error when you `package require Itk`? Were tcl-tk and ActiveTcl installed when you installed Itk? If not, and they are now, try re-installing Itk.